# How to annotate marginal plots / distribution plots in seaborn jointgrid / jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotations, seaborn

I did not find anything in this direction, but if I am wrong please let me know.

The question is posed both for the jointgrid method and for the jointplot method from seaborn, since both provide me with the same basic results so far. But if one the methods is better for the following question thats no problem. Here is an example of my jointplot so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=['x','y'])

fig=sns.jointplot(x=df['x'],y=df['y'])
fig=fig.plot_joint(plt.scatter)
fig=fig.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,kde=False)
```

resulting in

[image]

Now I want to comment the distribution graphics on the x and y axis with text. Finally, above each bar end there should be a percentage of the total distribution of this bins. But I don't know how to connect it.

With a normal distplot my code looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=['x','y'])

total = float(len(df['x']))
ax=sns.distplot(df['x'],kde=False)
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    print(p)
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height,
            '{:1.0f}'.format((height/total)*100),
            ha="center")
```

[image]

But how do I get the annotation on the distribution plots in the jointplot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are plotting things twice. You just need to plot it once and then extract the patches and use text for annotating with the right coordinates

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=['x','y'])
total = float(len(df['x']))

fig=sns.jointplot(x=df['x'],y=df['y'])

for p in fig.ax_marg_x.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    fig.ax_marg_x.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,height,
            '{:1.0f}'.format((height/total)*100), ha="center")

for p in fig.ax_marg_y.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    fig.ax_marg_y.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width(),p.get_y()+p.get_height()/2., 
            '{:1.0f}'.format((width/total)*100), va="center")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right with jointplot it is not necessary to fill the plot again. Just with jointgrid. I just did not know how to adress the margin plot - now with: " fig.ax_marg_x.patches ". Thanks !